# Transforming Android project into JAR file

Tags: java, android, jar

I have a Android project and this project uses one JAR file and have a library associated.
So, my doubt is: 
If i export my android project into a JAR file, the JAR file get that two other "projects" (the JAR and the library associated)?
I really need to export my project, so please help me.

Comment: I suppose you are exporting .apk and not .jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are building with Eclipse. Make sure you check the libraries for Export in the Properties-Java Build Path-Order and Export. Eclipse does not add the libraries for export by default.

Comment: So, i only have to check the libraries and the JAR file of my project will have them?

Comment: Yes, but of course you will have to add them to the Build Path first. And I suppose you are building an APK file, instead of JAR.

Comment: Uhh, in fact i need to export a JAR file. Because in the group that i work we have other project, that needs to use my part of the project.

Comment: OK, but then your JAR includes your code, not the other ones, which it just uses. When your group builds the application they then include all the JARs that the application needs. So you just produce your JAR and provide the other JARs for the group to be included in the build path of the application project.